# $.ajax data is null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to save the record in the database. I have been doing this thing but I don't know for what reason it is giving me this error. Any help will be appreciated. I don't know why the data is null. Please refer to the error show in below screenshot:

> data is not defined

[image: data is undefined.]

```
 function submit(amount) {
    var _url = ' /Home/SaveDepositedAmount';
    console.log(_url);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { ShowLoading(); },
        url: _url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { amount: amount },
    })
    .done(function (data) {
```

Server side code is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveDepositedAmount(int amount)
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        int userId = Authentication.Instance.User.UserId;
        result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with asp but here are few things that come to my mind with php + ajax.  It's worth checking out. Replace `done` with `always` - check if You got result. Place debug break one line below - not sure if in current line You will see the *data* value.  Again no idea about debuging asp., - add breakpoint in Your asp code and check if debugger stops in Your method when You fire Ajax event. Also in PHP You just `echo` string in method so try using something like that in ASP.

Answer (score 0):

You’re passing an object through to the server side but it’s only expecting an int. 
Create an object with 1 property (int Amount) and use that instead of the int for your server side parameter

Comment: i have created a class with an int property. now my action fires but the amount is 0

Comment: Try changing your contentType to be "application/json"